# Different Index in python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm a newbie to python and I have a question that I can't answer it. Please help me!

For example, I have an array in python:

index: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

value: a | b | c | d | e | f |

I can read value from the 5th slot of this array by using 2 ways:

- print array[4]
- print array[-2]

So what is the fastest way to access into the 5th position on this array?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Strange question! What is faster: to wink with the left or right eye?

Comment: The speed difference ought to be so small that there is no need to care about the difference on the overwhelming majority of cases. Use the one which captures your intuition better.

Comment: It should be noted that in this case, the lookup should be used based on the intent of the programmer: positive index means that if items are appended to the list, the positive index will still get you the right item; negative index means if new items are inserted somewhere in the list, the intended item still remains at the given index counted from the right side.

Comment: @Rainy: Yeah helpful information :) But in my case, there is a fixed list that contains more than one million-billion items (10^18 items)! I have to analyse structure of data when it stored in database by using a list!

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know. It would seem to me that they're equivalently fast, but that's what profiling is for, so let's do it!

```
import timeit

setup = '''the_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']'''

timeit.timeit('the_list[4]', setup)
timeit.timeit('the_list[-2]', setup)
```

for me, those values were:

```
0.12980895690317062
```

and

```
0.12949802723105344
```

Which shows positive indexing ~3/10000 of a second faster over 10,000 iterations.

Comment: @CalvinFroedge I think we reached the same conclusion though. It's just statistical noise.

Comment: Indeed, haha.  Either way, fun to actually test stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

They're both very close to constant time.

You may find this helpful:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

When I run this many times and average the results, a[-2] actually runs a bit faster...but the difference is so small it probably won't matter even on huge data sets.

```
from datetime import datetime

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

startTime = datetime.now()

for i in xrange(0,10000000):
    a[4]

print(datetime.now()-startTime)


startTime = datetime.now()

for i in xrange(0,10000000):
    a[-2]

print(datetime.now()-startTime)
```

Comment: Have you ever try to a "big" list? From 10^15 items? Of course it will be loaded on RAM :)

Answer (score 0):

Just [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit):

c:>py -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]" "y=x[4]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0458 usec per loop

c:>py -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]" "y=x[4]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0459 usec per loop

c:>py -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]" "y=x[4]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0489 usec per loop

c:>py -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]" "y=x[-2]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0448 usec per loop

c:>py -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]" "y=x[-2]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.045 usec per loop

c:>py -m timeit -s "x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]" "y=x[-2]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.045 usec per loop

Negligible difference.  In these timings it looks like the negative value is a few nanoseconds faster (on my system anyway).